# Eliminate results

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

Meta tag [results](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/results) has four questions, zero followers, and zero utility.  Can we nuke it?

Comment: For tags with few questions that are obviously worthless, you can dive right in and remove them yourself without asking for community consensus. Go for it!

Comment: @Excellll: OK, 2 out of 2 sounds like consensus to me.